# Is there a jQuery plugin to make every <div> scrollable?

Tags: jquery, css

Does anyone know of a JQuery plugin that could make any `<div>` scrollable? I have several containers and I only want them to be 300px, and some are larger so i need to make them scrollable.

Comment: Is CSS not a better solution here? `.myElement { height: 300px; overflow: scroll; }`

Comment: Knew I should have posted that as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should just be a job for CSS.

```
div.scrollable {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

(I assume you mean 300 pixels tall, not 300 pixels wide.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a need for javascript, less jQuery -- just use good ol' fashion CSS `overflow`

```
.myContainers {height:300px; overflow:auto;}
```

Read up about `overflow` over at [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html) to see some differences and options.

Answer (score 1):

css:

```
div.mydivs {
height:300px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<DIV style = "width:300px; height:300px; overflow:scroll">content</DIV>`

The content will be scrollable as soon as its width or height goes greater than 300px;

Comment: Well I did not read your question well. But do you really need a jquery plugin for this...